# Transition not applying for width in Tailwindcss v2

Tags: tailwind-css, css-transitions

I'm using Tailwndcss in my React Project. I want to change the width of the div depending on the value of useState hook. It's working but the width changes suddenly despite of adding transition classes. All I want to do is just to make this transition slow and smooth.
Following is the code of my component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Sidebar() {
  
  const [showMenuIcons, setshowMenuIcons] = useState(false);
  
    return (
      <div className={`h-fit bg-white shadow-lg border-l-2 relative z-10 ${showMenuIcons ? "w-fit transition-width duration-1000 ease-in-out" : "w-1/2 transition-width duration-1000 ease-in-out"} transition-width duration-1000 ease-in-out`} onClick={()=>{setshowMenuIcons(true)}}>
        <p>lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    );
  
}

export default Sidebar;
```

And here is tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      transitionProperty: {
        'width': 'width'
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of the tailwind classes does change the effect it has on the styling.
Check about it in [Tailwind Sorting](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/automatic-class-sorting-with-prettier#how-classes-are-sorted). They explain this sorting need and offer a way to automatically sort the classes using a plugin.

Also following the example in the Transition Property Documentation, the transition property goes first followed by the timing function and then the duration of the transition.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function Sidebar() {
  
  const [showMenuIcons, setshowMenuIcons] = useState(false);
  
    return (
      <div className={`transition-width ease-in-out duration-1000 h-fit bg-white shadow-lg border-l-2 relative z-10 ${showMenuIcons ? "w-fit" : "w-1/2"}`} onClick={()=>{setshowMenuIcons(true)}}>
        <p>lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    );
  
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Hope it is yet helpful :)